# Empty array using scan functrion ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm just getting started in ruby and I have some trouble understanding the `scan` method:

```
my_string = "0000000001000100"
string_group = my_string.scan('/...../')
puts string_group
puts string_group.class
```

It displays that I've got an array but the array is empty. It can't come from my regex because I tested it and tried with another one:

```
'/[01]{5}/'
```

Why do I get an empty array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because regexes in Ruby are literal, not strings -- you have single quotes around your regex, so `scan` is searching for the literal string `/...../` rather than matches to the regex `/...../`. Try this instead:

```
my_string = "0000000001000100"
string_group = my_string.scan(/...../)
```

Which gives this:

```
["00000", "00001", "00010"]
```